# Script to delete file based on its name

Tags: bash

Need some opinion on my scripting. I have some files like below format:-

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 12 15:56 hostdata_mm-xxx1_2018_04_03.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 12 15:56 hostdata_mm-xxx1_2018_04_04.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 12 15:56 hostdata_mm-xxx1_2018_04_05.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 12 15:56 hostdata_mm-xxx1_2018_04_06.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 12 15:56 hostdata_mm-xxx1_2018_04_07.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 12 15:56 hostdata_mm-xxx1_2018_04_08.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 12 15:56 hostdata_mm-xxx1_2018_04_09.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 12 15:56 hostdata_mm-xxx1_2018_04_10.csv
```

I need to have 1 file only which is yesterday's data, so, my script is like this:-

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x
wd=/root/test
yest=$(date -d "yesterday" '+%Y_%m_%d')

cd $wd
for f in *[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9].csv; do
date=${f#*}
date=${date%.csv}
date=`echo $date | rev`
date=${date:0:10}
date=`echo $date | rev`
(( $date < $yest )) && rm $f
done
```

However, I got this error

```
/usr/local/bin/testdelfile: line 15: ((: 2018_04_03: value too great for base (error token is "2018_04_03")
/usr/local/bin/testdelfile: line 15: ((: 2018_04_04: value too great for base (error token is "2018_04_04")
/usr/local/bin/testdelfile: line 15: ((: 2018_04_05: value too great for base (error token is "2018_04_05")
/usr/local/bin/testdelfile: line 15: ((: 2018_04_06: value too great for base (error token is "2018_04_06")
/usr/local/bin/testdelfile: line 15: ((: 2018_04_07: value too great for base (error token is "2018_04_07")
/usr/local/bin/testdelfile: line 15: ((: 2018_04_08: value too great for base (error token is "2018_04_08")
/usr/local/bin/testdelfile: line 15: ((: 2018_04_09: value too great for base (error token is "2018_04_09")
/usr/local/bin/testdelfile: line 15: ((: 2018_04_10: value too great for base (error token is "2018_04_10")
```

Here is the debug mode

```
+ for f in '*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9].csv'
+ date=hostdata_mm-xxx1_2018_04_10.csv
+ date=hostdata_mm-xxx1_2018_04_10
++ echo hostdata_mm-xxx1_2018_04_10
++ rev
+ date=01_40_8102_1kmc-ym_atadtsoh
+ date=01_40_8102
++ echo 01_40_8102
++ rev
+ date=2018_04_10
+ ((  2018_04_10 < 2018_04_12  ))
/usr/local/bin/testdelfile: line 15: ((: 2018_04_10: value too great for base (error token is "2018_04_10")
```

please advice

Answer (score 1):

`(( ... ))` operator in bash expects arithmetic value. The `2018_04_10` is a string and so you get an error. Use `[[ ... ]]` to do string comparison.

However with date, I would advice to convert to numerical timestamp `date +%s` in order to compare it with `(( ... ))`.

You can change your script to have:

```
yest=$(date -d "yesterday" '+%s')
for f in *[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9].csv; do
   date=$(sed -r 's/.*([0-9]{4})_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2}).csv/\1-\2-\3/' <<< $f | xargs date +%s -d)
   (( $date < $yest )) && rm $f
done
```

Comment: Tried your script but it deletes all of the files. What I did was:-

1. Add (touch) one more file in the same directory called hostdata_mm-xxx1_2018_04_12.csv (yesterday's file based on its name not timestamp)

2. run your script

Comment: Issue resolved after changing the operator in my original script. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the script is that an inappropriate operator is used for the string comparison. Just replace `(( ... ))` with `[[ ... ]]` in 14th line and the script will work fine.

More info can be found at http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

I would like to suggest a simpler solution. With find you can exclude by name the file you want to keep and then delete the other files in the directory:

```
find . -not -name "hostdata_mm-xxx1_$(date -d 'yesterday' '+%Y_%m_%d').csv" -type f -exec rm {} ";"
```

Comment: while your answer might be useful to other visitors, the OP asked to identify the bug in his script. Could you also explain what is wrong with his script?

Comment: @GeorgiY, issue resolved after changing the operator. Thanks!

BTW, your simplified command removes all files as it checks timestamp of file creation instead of timestamp on file name.

Comment: @user240614 ОК. Could you recheck the command? The command use -name argument rather the -ctime/mtime argument. The latter are used to find files by date of crate/modification.